# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image

Tags: php, imagick

I am using php Imagick for uploading cropped image using `cropImage' after that I want to resize that cropped image using 'resizeImage'. Here image cropping is working but resize image is showing exception my code is below.

upload.php

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $newUploadDir. $newfilename);
 cropImage($newUploadDir.$newfilename,$newUploadDirSmall.$newfilename,$x,$y,$w,$h);
 resizeImage($newUploadDirSmall.$newfilename,$newUploadDirSm.$newfilename,211, 50, 0, 0, true, false);
```

MagikLib.php

```
 <?php
function cropImage($source,$destination, $startX, $startY, $width, $height)
{
    $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($source));
    $imagick->cropImage($width, $height, $startX, $startY);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
    $imagick->writeImage($destination);
}
function resizeImage($source,$destination, $width, $height, $filterType, $blur, $bestFit, $cropZoom)
{
    //The blur factor where > 1 is blurry, < 1 is sharp.
    $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($source));
    $imagick->resizeImage($width, $height, $filterType, $blur, $bestFit);
    $cropWidth = $imagick->getImageWidth();
    $cropHeight = $imagick->getImageHeight();

    if ($cropZoom) {
        $newWidth = $cropWidth / 2;
        $newHeight = $cropHeight / 2;

        $imagick->cropimage(
            $newWidth,
            $newHeight,
            ($cropWidth - $newWidth) / 2,
            ($cropHeight - $newHeight) / 2
        );

        $imagick->scaleimage(
            $imagick->getImageWidth() * 4,
            $imagick->getImageHeight() * 4
        );
    }
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    $imagick->writeImage($destination);
}
?>
```

MagicLib.php is reffered from http://phpimagick.com/Imagick/cropImage and  http://phpimagick.com/Imagick/resizeImage

cropImage is working properly and saving image to folder but resizeImage is showing following errors

```
  Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/a/public_html/img/MagikLib.php:7) in /home/a/public_html/img/MagikLib.php on line 34

    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image `/home/a/public_html/img/images//b6d767d2f8ed5d21a44b0e5886680cb9/user/sm/image1.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2709' in /home/a/public_html/img/MagikLib.php:35 Stack trace: #0 /home/a/public_html/img/MagikLib.php(35): Imagick->writeimage('/home/a/pu...') #1 /home/a/public_html/img/upload1.php(74): resizeImage('/home/a/pu...', '/home/a/pu...', 211, 50, 0, 0, true, false) #2 {main} thrown in /home/a/public_html/img/MagikLib.php on line 35
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: /home/a/public_html/img/images//b6d767d2f8ed5d21a44b0e5886680cb9/user/sm/  is this dir exists and the www-data user have the x permission on this path

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EBDjBRRk this is my complete code please see once

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by the dir is not exists.

add this code:

```
$destinationPath = dirname($destination);
`mkdir -p $destinationpath`;
```

before

```
$imagick->writeImage($destination);
```

To recursively create path.

Comment: $newUploadDirLarge=$uploadDir."/".$userFolder."/cover/large/";
$newUploadDirSmall=$uploadDir."/".$userFolder."/cover/fit/";
$newUploadDirSm=$uploadDir."/".$userFolder."/profile/sm/"; remove the '/' for uploadir have the / at the end

Comment: Yes it is working but showing following warning. How can I remove this warning `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/a/public_html/img/imagikMethods.php:7) in /home/a/public_html/img/imagikMethods.php on line 34`

Comment: remove  header("Content-Type: image/jpg"); in the function resizeimage, for it have seted in the cripimage function.

Comment: just as the comment above, you use header("Content-Type: image/jpg"); twice, remove the header("Content-Type: image/jpg"); in resizeimage function

Answer (score 0):

`imagick` needs to have the `write` permission

so after install `imagick` with this command:

```
sudo apt install php-imagick
```

you need to go to this file:

```
/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

and edit this line:

```
< policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" / >
```

to this:

```
< policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" / >
```

after this, you will give `imagick` permission to write

[source](https://www.positronx.io/laravel-convert-pdf-document-to-image-tutorial/)